# Testing for a difference

Tags: categorical-data

Here's the scenario:
Students watch 2 videos for several different areas of content. Each video includes various examples.

If I know the average number of students who included an example in their notes from video 1 (across the different contents) and the average number of students who included an example in their notes from video 2, how do I tell if there is a significant difference?

I am trying to see if examples from video 1 are more likely to appear in the students' notes than the examples from video 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question reads as if this is a within-group experiment, i.e. the subjects are administered both treatments. The same subject watches both videos and could refer to only Video1, only Video2, or both Video1 and Video2 (as tabulated below). Therefore, you could try comparing the treatments via *within-subjects t-test*.

```
+----------+------------+-------------+
| Subject  | Video1     | Video2      |
+----------+------------+-------------+
| 1        | 1          | 2           |
| 2        | 0          | 0           |
| 3        | 3          | 1           | 
+----------+------------+-------------+
```